# how to import loadingController in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an app running on ionic 2, but I upgraded it to ionic 3 and after upgrading, some ionic plugins do not work, as is the case with the LoadingController and even the Platform.

generating the error "Cannot find name 'LoadingController'".

I looked at the ionic doc and did not figure out how to import them now

Follow my code:

```
import { LoadingController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular'

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 providers: [ ProfileService, AlertService ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, 
   public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
   private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
   private loginService: LoginService, 
   private profileService: ProfileService,
   private _alertService: AlertService,
   private platform: Platform ) {
    router.events.subscribe((data) => {
      this.path = data.url.substr(1);
    })

    this.getUserName();
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        history.go(-1)
      });
   });  
 }}
```

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-04-05

Comment: Ty man, this resolved my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LoadingController**
[ionic 3 loadingController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) link

**home.html**

```
    <ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Loading</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <button ion-button (click)="loading()">Show Loading</button>

</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
export class LoadingPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
  }
  loading(){
    let load = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content:'Please Wait....',
      duration: 3000
    });
    load.present();
  }
}
```